# Question about Plutus smart contract which always succeeds

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, haskell

Can anyone explain in detail why this script, https://github.com/james-iohk/Alonzo-testnet/blob/update-cabal-1.29.0/resources/plutus-sources/plutus-alwayssucceeds/src/Cardano/PlutusExample/AlwaysSucceeds.hs, results in the following output?

```
Writing output to: 
alwayssucceeds.plutus
"Log output"
[]
"Ex Budget"
ExBudget {exBudgetCPU = ExCPU 297830, exBudgetMemory = ExMemory 1100}
```

Thanks, Myles

Answer (score 1):

The output seems to be generated by [this](https://github.com/james-iohk/Alonzo-testnet/blob/update-cabal-1.29.0/resources/plutus-sources/plutus-alwayssucceeds/app/plutus-alwayssucceeds.hs) Haskell script (plutus-alwayssucceeds.hs) sitting in the parent folder of the script you linked. "plutus-alwayssucceeds.hs" is defined as the entry point of the executable defined in cabal file [here](https://github.com/james-iohk/Alonzo-testnet/blob/update-cabal-1.29.0/resources/plutus-sources/plutus-alwayssucceeds/plutus-alwayssucceeds.cabal#L65).

When you run command like `cabal build`, cabal will build "plutus-alwayssucceeds.hs" as an executable, which, when executed, will print out the log pasted in the question above. Notice that the actual plutus script (alwayssucceeds.plutus) is generated by function "writePlutusScript" [here](https://github.com/james-iohk/Alonzo-testnet/blob/update-cabal-1.29.0/resources/plutus-sources/plutus-alwayssucceeds/app/plutus-alwayssucceeds.hs#L22).